# fastest way to find min euclidean distance between two arrays

Tags: python, loops, euclidean-distance

I have two arrays of x,y,z coordinates, (e.g. a=[(x1,y1,z1)...(xN,yN,zN)], b = [(X1,Y1,Z1)...(XN,YN,ZN)] ).  I need the fastest way to iterate through them and find the indices of b with the minimum euclidean distance to each point in a.  here's the catch.  I'm using a modified/weighted euclidean equation.  Currently I'm doing two for loops which admittedly is the slowest way to do it.

b typically has around 500 coordinate sets to choose from, but a can have tens-to-hundreds of thousands

as an example:

```
a = (1,1,1), b = [(87,87,87),(2,2,2),(50,50,50)]
```

would return index 1.

Comment: I think O(N^2) is a reasonable complexity for this problem. If the only metric you care about is time you can unroll the loops or create multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) of array **b** and find the nearest distance of a coordinate in array **a** by traversing down the tree.

For array **a** of size n and array **b** of size m, the complexity would be O(mlog(m)) for building the tree and O(nlog(m)) for finding all the nearest distances.